# System.Xml Version 4 conflict with version 2.0.5.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, xna, system.xml

I have been fighting with this issue for a couple hours, and reading just about everything I can find on it. I have a WP7 xna game that references System.XML version 2.0.5.0. This references the content pipeline project. In this project references the pipeline project I created. I removed the System.XML references from the pipeline project but it didn't make any difference.It is referencing System.XML version 4.0.0.0 somewhere since I get this info in the output when I build.

No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

The issue is that the SL project will not build because it is trying to use version 4 and must have 2.0.5.0. It gives me the following error.

Building content threw FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: So wait, you have a game project, a Content project, and a Content Pipeline Extension Library? What is referencing what, exactly? The Content project should reference the Pipeline Extension, the game should not.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. The Game project references the Content Project which references the Pipeline. Thanks for helping me clarify that. 
The error comes out of the game project though.